# How to flash S32K148 with VS CODE

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio-code, nxp-microcontroller

I'm working on S32K148 NXP, and as I'm a beginner I would like to flash it using the vs code editor and then put it in a docker container. My problem returns errors, but on the S32DS I manage to flash it. can you help me to flash on vs code please???

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried? E.g. code or the steps you try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.